# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Chrome not working

Tags: java, javascript, google-chrome, dwr

I have an application launching an applet. When I try to click on the login button in Chrome I get the following error

```
applet.htm:54 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
engine.js:1262 console.trace()
engine.js:1262 dwr.engine._debug
engine.js:1263 Error: TypeError, undefined is not a function
```

Code applet.htm line 54(Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function) :

```
function initApplet() {
    while(ctiApplet.isActive()==false) {

    }
```

lines 1257 - 1281 of engine.js

```
/** @private Used internally when some message needs to get to the     programmer */
dwr.engine._debug = function(message, stacktrace) {
  var written = false;
  try {
    if (window.console) {
      if (stacktrace && window.console.trace) window.console.trace();
      window.console.log(message);
      written = true;
    }
    else if (window.opera && window.opera.postError) {
      window.opera.postError(message);
      written = true;
    }
  }
  catch (ex) { /* ignore */ }

  if (!written) {
    var debug = document.getElementById("dwr-debug");
    if (debug) {
      var contents = message + "<br/>" + debug.innerHTML;
      if (contents.length > 2048) contents = contents.substring(0, 2048);
      debug.innerHTML = contents;
    }
  }
};
```

Really can't understand why it is undefined. Its like it can't get a hold on the applet so doesn't realise its loaded. works on IE8. If anyone can shed any light on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a similar question and answer at [Call Applet.getMethod() with javascript throws error msg : TypeError: Applet.getMethod() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298597/call-applet-getmethod-with-javascript-throws-error-msg-typeerror-applet-get), that is about Firefox but the issue is the same: page completion may occurr before applet initialization.

A first solution it is to simply put a delay before the applet init phase:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("document ready");
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log("calling openSession...");
        document.myApplet.openSession();
    }, 2000);
});
```

But you can't always be sure that the delay is enough.
A more complex solution may be to cicle at most a number of times (e.g. 20), invoking the init method, until this does not become accessible (i.e. not "undefined"), waiting for some time (e.g. 125 ms) before retrying.

Comment: thanks, yes this appears to be the best solution. sometimes it works and sometimes I get the above error so the delay is best.